# C++ Variadic Template Parameters to Linear Hierarchy

Tags: c++, templates, hierarchy, variadic

Is it possible to generate a linear hierarchy from variadic template parameters? For example:

```
GenLinearHierarchy<A,B,C,D,...> linHierarchy;
```

Generates a hierarchy where A -> B -> C -> D -> ... -> Empty (where the -> symbol stands for inherits from).

Where the template parameters (template template... parameters) have signatures such as:

```
template <class Base, class Plate> class A;
```

Where Base is the class above A in the hierarchy and Plate is the 'most derived' class (for example D< E<...>, A<...> >).

So far I've been unsuccessful - starting to wonder whether I'm going in circles (I do keep running into cyclic problems).

Sorry about the confusion - here is a 'concrete solution' (one which I'm not too fond of):

```
// Linear Hierarchy

#include <iostream>

template <class Base, class Floor>
class D : public Base
{
public:
};

template <class Base, class Floor>
class C : public Base
{
public:
        void Fire()
        {
                static_cast<Floor*>(this)->Handle();
        }
};

template <class Base, class Floor>
class B : public Base
{
public:
        void Handle()
        {
                std::cout << "Handled" << std::endl;
        }
};

class _FINISH {};

class _START : public B<C<D<_FINISH, _START>, _START, _START> {};

int main()
{
        typedef _START A;
        A a;
        a.Fire();

        return 0;
}
```

So, I'm still looking for a 'GenLinearHierarchy' class which can generate something like above, but with an instatiation like this:

```
GenLinearHierarchy<B,C,D> linHierarchy;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you want `A` to inherit from.  You can't change classes `Base` and `Plate`, only what `A` is composed of, but perhaps this is not what you mean and it only exemplifies my confusion.

Comment: This is one of those questions where a picture will literally speak a thousand words.

Comment: Or perhaps you want to solve the inheritance hierarchy given a set of classes... Now that'd be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can let `Plate` be the most derived type, as that would mean the overall type would have to have itself as one of its own template parameters. This is the closest I've gotten:

```
struct Empty {};

template <template <class> class Head, template <class> class... Tail>
struct GenLinearHierarchy
{
    typedef Head<typename GenLinearHierarchy<Tail...>::type> type;
};

template <template <class> class Tail>
struct GenLinearHierarchy<Tail>
{
    typedef Tail<Empty> type;
};

template <class Base> struct A : Base {};
template <class Base> struct B : Base {};
template <class Base> struct C : Base {};
template <class Base> struct D : Base {};

static_assert(std::is_same< typename GenLinearHierarchy<A,B,C,D>::type
                          , A<B<C<D<Empty>>>>                          >::value
             , "");
```

---

**EDIT** I think I've got what you wished for. Good luck trying to read it. You've only got yourself to blame. :)

```
struct Empty {};

template <class MostDerived,
          template <class, class> class Head,
          template <class, class> class... Tail>
struct GenLinearHierarchyInner
{
    typedef Head<typename GenLinearHierarchyInner<MostDerived,
                                                  Tail...>::type,
                 MostDerived> type;
};

template <class MostDerived,
          template <class, class> class Tail>
struct GenLinearHierarchyInner<MostDerived, Tail>
{
    typedef Tail<Empty, MostDerived> type;
};

template <template <class, class> class... Types>
struct GenLinearHierarchy : GenLinearHierarchyInner<GenLinearHierarchy<Types...>,
                                                    Types...>::type
{};

template <class Base, class> struct A : Base {};
template <class Base, class> struct B : Base {};
template <class Base, class> struct C : Base {};
template <class Base, class> struct D : Base {};

typedef GenLinearHierarchy<A,B,C,D> ABCD;

static_assert(std::is_base_of< A<B<C<D<Empty, ABCD>, ABCD>, ABCD>, ABCD>
                             , ABCD                                      >::value
             , "");
```

Comment: That is awesome! Can you think of a way for classes higher in the hierarchy to invoke functions in lower classes? This was why I wanted each element to know the lowest element - so it could propagate 'events' up through the hierarchy. Still, that is a really cool solution!

Comment: @user3513346 Updated. Be careful what you wish for. (Can't quite believe I wrote this at 5am.)

Comment: Haha looks perfect :) That is awesome Oktalist. Wish I could've come up with that myself! Not sure why you are scared of it :P

Answer (score 0):

It's probably something like this...

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class GenLinearHierarchy : public T, public GenLinearHierarchy<Args...> {};

template<typename T>
class GenLinearHierarchy<T> : public T {};
```

Comment: This is getting towards what I'm trying to do - I've actually tried this. However, two things - this isn't exactly a LinearHierarchy, it is more of a 'step' hierarchy (G -> A, (G -> B, (G -> C.....))). Secondly, related to the first point, the template parameters do no directly inherit from the next template parameter in the set (so they can't say stuff like Base::DoSomething). I'll modify my question to give you guys a 'concrete' solution. Thanks :)